# Can not run MSBuild Community Task 'WebDirectoryDelete' and 'WebDirectoryCreate'

Tags: msbuild

I have a new default ASP.net website and use MSBuild Community Task WebDirectoryDelete to delete and WebDirectoryCreate to create the IIS virtual directory.

I can't get it done. It raise error : Unknow error 0x80005000. I retry by running the msbuild under "Run as Administrator" but the errors still appear.

I'm using Windows 7 and dotNet Framework 3.5

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Windows7 uses IIS7, which is inherently different from prior versions of IIS. You can either enable IIS6 metabase compatibility on your machine (under Programs and Features), or change your directory creation to use the new [IIS7 .net api](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/165/how-to-use-microsoftwebadministration/).

Comment: Please show me how to "change your directory creation to use the new IIS7 .net api"!